# monodroid Sample GLCube build error

Tags: xamarin.android

I have installed monodroid and I am trying to build monodroid sample GLCube with VS 2010. I get a compile error for the following line in the CreateFrameBuffer function on the source. I am using latest Android SDK and Mono SDK (trial), and I am building for Android 2.2.  Are these samples only meant for certain versions of Android Open GL?  I just used the default platform of the sample solution/project file. Why won't the sample compile?

Line:   GraphicsMode = new GraphicsMode (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false);

Error:  'OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
E:\Dev\xamarin-monodroid-samples-4d92f45\GLCube\PaintingView.cs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have checked out the sample code from github after a comitter broke it.

I suggest getting an earlier commit, say, [this one](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/monodroid-4.0.6).

Comment: Thanks. The revision you specified works for me.  I had assumed the latest repository code would at least build since it was checked in a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, since I have not actually looked at the code in question, but from the snippet you posted, and the error you are getting, it looks like you need to declare a variable to assign the GraphicsMode object to.

Ex:

```
GraphicsMode gmMode = new GraphicsMode(16,0,0,0,0,0,false);
```